# Restful Flask Python

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I am new to python and flask, trying learning by building a restful customer database, so this is in dataModels.py:

very plain:

```
class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self, pID, name, address, email, custNO, agent ):
        self.pID = pID
        self.name = name
        self.address =address
        self.email = email
        self.custNO = custNO
        self.agent = agent

class CustomerList(list):
    def addCustomer(self, pID, name, address, email, custNO, agent):
        self.append((false, pID, name, address, email, custNO, agent))
    def custCount(self):
        return len (self)
```

this is in views.py:

```
api.add_resource(CustomerList, '/customer')
```

I am getting a "AttributeError: type object 'CustomerList' has no attribute 'as_view'" error. What am I missing?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-Restful expects that you will pass it a subclass of [`flask.ext.restful.Resource`](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#flask.ext.restful.Resource) but you are passing it a class that is not a subclass of `Resource` and which does not provide an `as_view` method (which comes from [`flask.views.View`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.views.View), which [`restful.Resource`](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#flask.ext.restful.Resource) is itself a subclass of).

You will want to make both `Customer` and <strike>`CustomerList`</strike> `Customers` [`Resource`](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#flask.ext.restful.Resource) sub-classes:

```
class Customer(Resource):
    def __init__(self, p_id, name, address, email, customer_number, agent):
        self.p_id = p_id
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.email = email
        self.customer_number = customer_number
        self.agent = agent

class Customers(Resource):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Customers, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._customer_list = []

    def add_customer(self, p_id, name, address, email, customer_number, agent):
        customer = Customer(p_id, name, address, email, customer_number, agent)
        self._customer_list.append(customer)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._customer_list)
```

Take a look at [the documentation's quickstart full example](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#full-example) for a fuller example of what you are trying to do.